# Excel SQL query brackets

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have a problem with this Excel SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [RawData$] 
WHERE [Temperature[°C]] <= 100 
  AND [Temperature[°C]] > 0 
  AND [Sample ID] AND [Freq [Hz]]
```

I need to know, how I can use the additional brackets in the query, like the "[°C]"

Thanks

PS.: I also tried a version like this, but it didn't work

```
SELECT * 
FROM [RawData$] 
WHERE [Temperature[[]°C]] <= 100  
  AND [Temperature[[]°C]] > 0 
  AND [Sample ID] AND [Freq [[]Hz]]
```

Comment: can you post a minmal example of your table? just a few rows

Comment: Sorry, this is not possible, there is too much data per line, even one line would be too much

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE "Temperature[c]"<=`  should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the fast Reply Actually this "works" for this 
`SELECT * FROM [RawData$] WHERE "Temperature[°C]"`

But when i add the "=" or "<" than it tells me: "Data type mismatch in criteria expression"